# How to count the number of occurence daily for each element in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counting, pandas-resample

Being working with a KPIs dataframe where I've a set of KPIs for different element and each KPI having a value hourly, e.g below.

The CSV text used to create the dataframe cand be found here : https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/4ta4

Main Dataframe :

[image: Main Dataframe]

filtering by an element :

[image: One element example]

Filtering by another element :

[image: Second element example]

What I want to do actually is to have the **Daily Occurence** for each element on it's own, I've tried with the **Resampling** functions but the result is global to the whole Dataframe and not **Cell** column wise.

Result when using **Resample" function :

[image: Resample function result]

While below is the desired result :

[image: Desired result]

Any suggestions ?

Comment: please provide a **minimal** example of input/output as **text** (to be able to copy/paste)

Comment: You can find the CSV used to create the input dataframe with this link : https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/4ta4

Comment: Unfortunately, it is neither minimal nor guaranteed to be available on the long term

Comment: Would you pelase tell me how to do so then ? as the text file is really long and would make the post less clear

Comment: Thats precisely the point, craft a dummy example that is only a few lines long and is sufficient to explain what you want to do

Comment: Please have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for more direction on creating a data sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IUUC, you can try groupby date and `Cell` column then compute group sizes.

```py
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
out = df.groupby([df['Time'].dt.date, 'Cell']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
```

```
print(out)

          Time        Cell  Count
0   2022-05-08   LAL0005_H      7
1   2022-05-08  LAL0005_H2     11
2   2022-05-08  LAL0005_I2      1
3   2022-05-08  LAL0005_Y2      4
4   2022-05-09   LAL0005_H      2
5   2022-05-09  LAL0005_H2      7
6   2022-05-09  LAL0005_Y2      1
7   2022-05-10   LAL0005_H      1
8   2022-05-10  LAL0005_H2      9
9   2022-05-11   LAL0005_H      1
10  2022-05-11  LAL0005_H2      8
11  2022-05-12   LAL0005_H      2
12  2022-05-12  LAL0005_H2      7
13  2022-05-13   LAL0005_H      4
14  2022-05-13  LAL0005_H2     10
15  2022-05-14   LAL0005_H      8
16  2022-05-14  LAL0005_H2     12
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but I've a question.

How did you get to that result (code) ?

I'm pretty new to pandas and I'm struggling as I can't use my logical/algorithmical thinking, from the little time working with it, I found myself googling things and methods and even with the full correct answer I still don't see any algorithmic reasoning pattern to get to that result. If you have any advices I will be grateful.

Comment: @DarKing Honestly I didn't get what you want with *What I want to do actually is to have the Daily Occurence for each element on it's own*. But your result pic is clear enough that you take `Time` and `Cell` as a group. That's why I use `.groupby([df['Time'].dt.date, 'Cell'])`. `GroupBy.size` is common api to compute the group size.